# update database record through html page using servlets

Tags: java, servlets

my request is going to update query in the else if condition but the records are not updating in the database
help me out of this situation
I didn't get any errors after clicking on update button the database record is not inserted in the database

```
// imports ...

public class RequestData extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<title>DataRetreving</title>");
        out.print("<body>");
        out.print("<table border=5 width=50% height=50% bgcolor=magenta align=center>");
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<th><b>id</b></th>");
        out.print("<th><b>name</b></th>");
        out.print("<th><b>address</b></th>");
        out.print("<th><b>action</b></th>");
        out.print("<th><b>actionupdate</b></th>");
        out.print("</tr>");
        Driver driver = new OracleDriver();
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE", "system",
                    "india124");
            Statement pst = connection.createStatement();
            if(request.getParameter("action")!=null && "delete".equals(request.getParameter("action")))
            {
                int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
                pst.executeUpdate("delete from employee where id="+id); 
            }
            else if(request.getParameter("id") != null
                    && request.getParameter("name") != null
                    && request.getParameter("address") != null              
                    && request.getParameter("update") != null 
                    && !"update".equals(request.getParameter("actionupdate")))
            {
              int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
              String name = request.getParameter("name");
              String address = request.getParameter("address");
              pst.executeQuery("insert into employee(id,name,address)"+"values("+id+",'"+name+"','"+address+"')");
            }
            else if(request.getParameter("actionupdate")!=null 
                    && "update".equals(request.getParameter("actionupdate"))) {
              int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")); 
              String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
              String address =request.getParameter("address");
              pst.executeUpdate("update employee set address='"+address+"',name='"+name+"'where id="+id+""); 
            } 

            ResultSet rst=pst.executeQuery("select *from employee");
            while (rst.next()) 
            {
                out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td align=center bgcolor=yellow><b> " + rst.getInt("id") + "</b></td>");
                out.print("<td align=center><b>" + rst.getString("name") + "</b></td>");
                out.print("<td align=center><b>" + rst.getString("address") + "</b></td>");
                out.print("<form align=center action=\"./requestdata\">");
                out.print("<td align=center bgcolor=yellow><a href=\"http://localhost:8082/RequestDataDemo/requestdata?id="
                  +rst.getInt("id")+"&action=delete\">DELETE</a></td>");
                out.print("<td align=center bgcolor=yellow><a href=\"http://localhost:8082/RequestDataDemo/requestdata?id="
                          +rst.getInt("id")+"&name="+rst.getString("name")+"&address="+rst.getString("address")+"&actionupdate=update\">UPDATE</a></td>");
                out.print("</tr>");
            }
            out.print("</table>");
            out.print("<br><br>");

            if(request.getParameter("actionupdate")!=null && "update".equals(request.getParameter("actionupdate"))) {
                 out.print("<form align=center action=\"./requestdata\">");
                 out.print("enter id  :<input type=\" text\" name = \" id \" value="+request.getParameter("id")+"><br><br>");
                 out.print("enter name: <input type=\"text\" name = \"name\" value="+request.getParameter("name")+"><br><br>");
                 out.print("enter address:<input type=\"text\" name = \"address \" value="+request.getParameter("address")+"><br><br>");
                 out.print(" <input type=\"submit\" value =\"update\"><br><br>");
                 out.print("</form>");
            }
            else
            {
              out.print("<form align=center action=\"./requestdata\">");
              out.print("eneter id  :<input type=" + "text" + " name = " + "id><br><br>");
              out.print("eneter name: <input type=" + "text" + " name = " + "name><br><br>");
              out.print("eneter address:<input type=" + "text" + " name = " + "address><br><br>");
              out.print(" <input type=" + "submit" + " value = " + "submit><br><br>");
              out.print(" <input type=" + "reset><br><br>");
              /* out.print("<input type='submit' value='delete'>"); */
              out.print("</form>");
            }
            out.print("</body>");
            out.print("</html>");
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

my request is going to update but the records are not updating in the database
help me out of this situation
I didn't get any errors after clicking on update button the database record is not inserted in the database

Comment: Use some kind of a profiling tool to see what is actually executed on the db, or output your execution string, and run it directly on the db and see what happens.

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: Split your code (see [Model-View-Controller pattern](https://www.guru99.com/jsp-mvc.html)), i.e. put the display part (all `out.print(...)`) into a JSP file, and also put the code for different actions into separate methods. It will be much easier to debug it then. And, of course, put some logging in place, to see what's happening and whether your code is executed in proper order.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to all the comments that you should refactor this code. But for a first try I guess it is important to see it working.

I think you have a bit of a logical problem here: What exactly do you send when you insert a new record? I couldn't find that part.

I am guessing you want the insert block to run, so this condition:

```java
else if(request.getParameter("id") != null&&request.getParameter("name")!=null&&request.getParameter("address")!=null &&request.getParameter("update")!=null &&!"update".equals(request.getParameter("actionupdate") ))
```

to be true. But if you look at the end of the line you want the "update" parameter to be present and "actionupdate" to be different than "update". But you are not setting these in your code. So this condition will always be false, hence the insert is never called.

When you press a submit button a parameter submit="" is sent to the server. This way you can tell which button was clicked. So maybe add a submit button with value="insert" and test if that is present to enter in the INSERT block.

Again, try to make this work by revisiting all your conditions and parameters and see when/if they are set and when they are true or not. And after that absolutely spend some time refactoring and practicing better techniques.

Comment: records are inserted but I am unable to update the record

Comment: Add a message to be printed in the block that does the update and see if it appears on the page. If not check again the conditions to enter that clock. If the message appears on page then maybe id is wrong

Comment: I got the id in the console but the name and address in the else -if block is not printing on console